# Copy drivers from shapekeys

Tags: shortcut, drivers, shape-keys

Basically i have one mesh (my character) and armature for that mesh full setup. A whole control rig and bunch of corrective shapekeys on my mesh which are driven by bones rotation (its daz3d mesh/armature).
Now i want to add 2nd mesh (clothes) which is rigged to the same armature and have the same number of corrective shapekeys, named the same as in my first mesh.

To make it more clear i just want to add clothes to my character and i have managed to do everything without much issues except drivers.
There is really lot of shapekeys and the way its build to stop clipping, clothes have the same shapekeys as character mesh.

I have searched around but couldn't find easy way to copy/link/transfer drivers from shapekeys of one mesh to other, atleast not fast.
I'd be glad even if i could drop copy driver/paste driver to some keyboard shortcut as right cliking menu gets tedious really fast.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I found it to work is to transfer vertex weights, transfer shape keys, join object to desired shapekey owner object, seperate back from original object and all the drivers should work properly. Good luck with it. Oh, and then you have to go through and unlink all other data from the original object, like UV maps, materials, modifiers and anything else that you don't want linked to it. And don't forget to unlink anything on the original object joined from the second object as well.